# Using existing database in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using multiple databases in a Django app.  The `default` database is the one Django creates for user authentication, etc. Then I have a `vo` database, with existing data, which I plan to use for the content generation.

I wanted the classes in `models.py` to link up to the existing tables in `vo`.  However, when I do

```
manage.py syncdb --database=vo
```

a set of new empty tables are created. BTW, it's a SQLite3 database.

How does one link existing tables in a database to the classes on `models.py` in Django?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want actual linking where changes in vo are reflected in queries, or is it enough to copy vo into default once?

Comment: Do you want to make a ForeignKey with multiple databases ?

Comment: It was actually enough just mirroring db into models.py. This was achieved with the answer below. Also, no need for ForeignKey. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. You need to add your db `vo` to settings.

if you have your database settings like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': os.path.join(DIR, 'django.sqlite3'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

Add `vo` database settings to it like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': os.path.join(DIR, 'django.sqlite3'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },

    # this your existing db 
    'vo': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(DIR, 'vo.sqlite'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

2. Then you can generate models automatically from the database.

   ```
   $ ./manage.py inspectdb --database=vo > your_app/models.py
   ```
3. Configure database routers.

Check out: [Using Django's Multiple Database Support](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1242/django_multiple_database_support)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. Now I just have to edit and refine the models.py it generated.