# Adding existing sqlite3 database to Django App

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Trying to follow this tutorial: https://knivets.com/how-to-integrate-django-with-existing-database/

and this SO: [Using existing database in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697337/using-existing-database-in-django)

My settings.py databases setup:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    # existing db I wan't to add
    'articles': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'articles.sqlite3'),

    }
}
```

It does detect and generates a model based on the table I'm interested in. I've added this model to models.py and

```
python manage.py dbshell --database=articles
```

does show the table and that it holds data. However, in Django /admin the table shows up but breaks when I try to add to it and none of the existing data appears. This is the error that it throws:

OperationalError at /admin/core/articles/

no such table: articles

I appreciate any help ya'll can offer here.

Comment: Do you not need to add `--database=articles` to the `dbshell` command?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I've updated the post to indicate that this indeed works as well but that the table still is throwing an error in the app.

Comment: You probably need to add a database router to tell django which database to use for that model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers